# Python Quandl - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio, quandl

Visual Studio 2017 - Empty Python Project
My code looks like this (yes just two lines):

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl
```

I have added the Quandl (3.2.0) environment to my Python 3.6 (64-bit) project.

Quandl is underlined in green.  A mouse hover reveals the following message:

```
Quandl: module

Unable to resolve "Quandl".  IntelliSense may be missing from this module.
```

When I run the program I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\P1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Quandl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'
```

I checked here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quandl and I have all of the other required distributions installed.

This is my first attempt at using Quandl, and I am relatively new to Python.

Note: I have created another 3 small Python programs in the same environment that don't use Quandl, but use pandas, numpy etc. They run fine.

Can anyone help me get past this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Quandl's old package was named `Quandl`. The new one, that uses their new API is called `quandl`. I don't know why they thought changing the name was a good idea, but it's what they did.

Answer (score 1):

OK... As usual immediately after posting....
The import statement should read:

import **q**uandl

The "**Q**" should be lowercase.

I'll leave this up here in case others fall for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jupyter notebook, open Anaconda Prompt and type

```
conda install quandl
```

then you can easily import it and if you are not using Jupyter Noteebook Try

```
pip install quandl
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest uninstall quandl.

and then, install using pip3

```
pip3 install quandl
```